# How do I make my script run when the content of my app changes?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, footable

Hello I want to implement in my mobile application (I use the ionic framework) some kind of data table and I was looking at the footables. When I use a footable in the index of my application works, but when it changes to other pages the tables of that pages do not work. The script of the footable only works once and is when the index page is loaded. This is the scripts

```
<script>
 jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable();
 });
</script>
```

In the page of footables (http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html#download) talk about the use of the .on method, but this does not work either

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').on({
        "init.ft.table": function(e, ft){
            // bind to the plugin initialize event to do something
        }
    }).footable();
});
</script>
```

The applications in ionic only have an index and within the ion-app tag where the application content loads

[image]

Comment: this is because other pages are loaded after you define footable binding so there will be no binding of event to the table that are in other pages. In other words there was no DOM available of other pages that's why your footable was working for index and not for other pages.